# Rotate text within a JS-generated <li>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a little script that will generate a custom number of slices for a circle. I am drawing the circle items like this: [generated circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nja66.png). With the following Javascript code:

```js
for () {
        menu.styleSheet += `li:nth-child(${i + 1}) {\n` +
                                `\ttransform: rotate(${currentDegrees}deg) skewY(${degreeOffset - 90}deg);\n` +
                             `}\n\n`;

        menu.styleSheet += `li:nth-child(${i + 1}) .text {\n` +
                               `\ttransform: skewY(${90 - degreeOffset}deg) rotate(${degreeOffset / 2}deg);\n` +
                           `}\n\n`;

        currentDegrees += degreeOffset;
    }
```

Right now, I am trying to achieve to transform the numbers (see the picture above) to always face upwards but currently, I am stuck. What is the best way to transform the rotation of the text, without also transforming the **li** as well or changing the position of the text? I want the numbers to stay at the same place as now, just face upwards without messing up the generated style.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a **p** inside the **li** and I was able to rotate the text without messing up the design.